# Display Hierarchy Tree with Order, Insert, Delete, Update Buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, hierarchy

I have been trying to figure out the best way to display my SQL Hierarchy client side for view / edit.  I have looked into nested gridview, treeview, building using stringbuilder and building using htmlgenericcontrol.

I have found the following problems:

1. Treeview doesn't allow for multiple links per node
2. Gridview doesn't seem to allow for infinite hierarchy style I have
3. stringbuilder doesn't allow for server side onclick controls
4. htmlgenericcontrol is tedious.

I wanted to ask the question on here before I move ahead with what I am doing building using htmlgenericcontrol.

My SQL Data looks like this:

Project Table

- ProjectID
- Project Name

Category Table

- CategoryID
- ProjectParentID
- CategoryParentID
- Category Name

Test Table

- TestID
- CategoryParentID
- Test Name

TDP Table

- TDPID
- TestParentID
- TDP Name

So hopefully it is clear there that the root is parent, then the category structure can be infinite followed by Tests in the Category that hold TDP's.

I wanted to know how to best display this in a indented list structure that would have buttons for order, insert, update, delete like this:

- Project                          | (add category)

  - Category1                      | (add category) | (edit) | -+

    - Test 1                       | (add tdp) | (edit) | -+

      - TDP1                     | (edit) | -+
    - Test 2                       | (add tdp) | (edit) | -+

      - TDP2                     | (edit) | -+
  - Category 2                      | (add category) | (edit) | -+

    - Category 3                   | (add category) | (edit) | -+

      - Test 3                   | (add tdp) | (edit) | -+